# Convert Ruby's times to C#

Tags: c#, ruby, function

I am trying to convert Ruby's [time](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Looping_with_for_and_the_Ruby_Looping_Methods#The_Ruby_times_Method) to C#, but I am stuck now.

Here's my try:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Times(this Int32 times, WhatGoesHere?)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            ???
    }
}
```

I am new to C#, and maybe this one should be easy, and I know I want to use Extensionmethods. But since functions are not 'first class ' in C#, I am stuck for now.

So, what parametertype should I use for of *WhatGoesHere?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) type:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Times(this Int32 times, Action<Int32> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            action(i);
    }
}

class Program
{
    delegate void Del();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        5.Times(Console.WriteLine);
        // or
        5.Times(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }
}
```

Also have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to learn about delegates.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about delegates.